# Regex, negative suffix

Tags: c#, regex, string-parsing

I have the following (key/value list) structure

**field:***value value value* **field:***value value value*

**classType:***type type2 ns.grrr.test3 _test4* **name_space.classType:***grrr.test5 test6*

I would like to be able to to parse the string into groups

**classType** - *the field*

- type       - *the values*
- type2
- ns.grrr.test3
- _test4

**name_space.classType**

- grrr.test5
- test6

one of my attempts sofar

```
^(?<field>((\w+\.?)+)\:)(?<value>(((\w+\.?)+)\s?)+)
```

which in expresso, the above does not work. I am able to get some parts to work but not using the desired groups

also tried:

```
(?<value>((?!\:)((\w+\.?)+\:?)))
```

where I try to make sure the value group will not accidently include a field
there are no special chars, only:

a-z A-Z 0-9 _ . -

any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

getting closer, this pulls all the values correctly except the last term  "test6"...

any help is welcomed :)

(thanks @ rfeague for the input on this one).

```
((?<field>(\w+\.?)+)[:]((?<value>(\w+\.?)+)\s)+)
```

Dave

Comment: What regex implementation do you use?

Comment: using C#, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: This isn't 100% right, so posted as comment instead of answer: ((?<field>[^:]+):((?<value>[^ :]+)[ \t]+)+)+
Results here: http://capgrabr.com/_0550d5f679b98057cbcc91e40e870f0e
gets everything except that last test6.

Comment: getting close, thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input I have the following which is bringing back the correct results for me

```
((?<field>(\w+\.?)+)[:]((?<value>(\w+\.?)+)(\s|$))+)
```

Answer (score 1):

This matches everything

```
(?<field>[^\s]+?):((?<value>[^\s]+)\s?)+
```

Comment: @dbones posted because in my test your regex didn't work, but if it is ok no problem :)

Comment: top man for sharing, the expression I noted works well in my C# project :)